# Show every subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is closed with respect to the usual metric?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, metric-spaces

How do I see that every subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is closed with respect to the usual metric $p(x,y) = x^Ty$ ?

I've seen some sweet results regarding Hilbert Spaces $\mathcal H$, especially that for a subspace $S$, $(S^{\bot})^\bot = S$, and this is true (in the case $\mathcal H = \mathbb R^n$) if $S$ is closed with respect to the metric given above.

I already know that $\mathbb R^n$ is complete.

Comment: You can proceed by induction on the dimension of the sub space.

Answer (score 4):

Every subspace is the kernel of a linear application (even of a projection !) which is continuous as we're in finite dimension, so that the subspace is closed.

Comment: Could you describe a little more for someone not expert ?

Comment: Take an orthonormal basis $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ of your subspace $F$. Complete it in an orthonormal basis $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of the total space and look a the linear map sending a vector of coordinate $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ to the vector of coordinate $(a_1,\ldots,a_d)$. This is obviously continuous, and $F$ is the kernel (inverse image of $\{0\}$, which is closed) by this linear map, so it is closed also, as the map is continuous. Don't hesitate to validate my answer if you're ok with it.

Comment: @user10000100_u I'm sorry, but isn't the kernel of said application just the set of all elements $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ such that $(x_1,\dots,x_d) =0$? Not a single element (besides 0) of $F$ belongs to the kernel. Or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Every subspace is also complete (since it is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^m$ for some $m$), and complete implies closed since every Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R^m\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ converges in that same $\Bbb R^m\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ we have that it is closed by definition (i.e. every convergent sequence of points in the set converges in the same set)

Answer (score 0):

Every subspace is the orthogonal complement of its orthogonal complement, so it is enough to show that the orthogonal complement of a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is closed.

Now the orthogonal complement of a subset $S$ of your vector space is the intersection of the orthogonal complements of the elements of $S$. Since the intersection of closed subsets is closed, this means that it is enough to show that the set $v^\perp$ of vectors orthogonal to a vector $v\in\mathbb R^n$ is closed.

Now $v^\perp=\{w\in\mathbb R^n:\langle w,v\rangle=0\}$ or, equivalently, $v^\perp$ is the kernel of the linear map $f_v:w\in\mathbb R^n\mapsto \langle w,v\rangle\in\mathbb R$. This means that it is enough to show that every linear map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is continuous.

You probably know how to do that.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know that the inner product is a continuous function, then the continuity of $f_v$ is almost immediate.