# The linear Lie algebra of a closed linear group is closed

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was reading Knapp's [Lie groups beyond an introduction](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817642594) and, in the first pages, he shows that the set of all tangent vectors to a given closed linear group $G$ at the identity matrix, that is
$$\mathfrak{g} = \{c'(0)\;|\; c\colon \mathbb{R}\to G \mbox{ is a smooth curve with } c(0)=I\} $$
is a Lie algebra taking $[X,Y] = XY-YX$ (and it's usually called the *linear Lie algebra of $G$*). In order to prove that the Lie braket is well defined he states that $\mathfrak{g}$ is closed, but I don't follow. How could I prove that $\mathfrak{g}$, as a subspace of the matrix space, is topologically closed? Any hints?

Another way of proving what he's trying to prove is that, by taking $X=c'(0)$ and $Y=d'(0)$ in $\mathfrak{g}$, proving that $XY = c'(0)d'(0)$ is in $\mathfrak{g}$ (thus, $XY-YX = [X,Y]\in \mathfrak{g}$ by being a linear combination of elements in $\mathfrak{g}$). The other question would then be: given $c(t)$ and $d(t)$ smooth curves, can I find a smooth curve $f(t)$ such that $f'(t) = c'(t)d'(t)$?, I tried doing integration by parts but I end in a $0=0$ type of scenario.

Comment: One way to see this is to prove $\frak{g}$ is a linear subspace:  If $\gamma '(0), \eta '(0), \in \frak{g}$, then $(\gamma \cdot \eta)'(0) = \gamma'(0)+\eta'(0)$.

Comment: That I know, I mean topologically closed.

Comment: Right, so now you should try to prove that a linear subspace of a finite dimensional real vector space is topologically closed.

Comment: Inspired on an answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138974/show-every-subspace-of-mathbb-rn-is-closed-with-respect-to-the-usual-metric/1138978#1138978) I came up with this: Consider $S\leq \mathbb{R}^m$ and $T\colon \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^m/S$ given by $T(x) = x+S$. $T$ is linear between finite-dimensional spaces and, so, it is continous. It is evident that $S = \ker T = T^{-1}(\{0\})$. Thus $S$ must be closed. Is it alright?

Comment: I found a fault in my argument, is $\{0\}$ closed in $\mathbb{R}^m/S$ with the subspace topology?, not necessarily.